# Adding private repository to Podfile but using credentials at install stage in Jenkins CI

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I would like to be able to add a private repository to my Podfile like so:

```
pod 'REDACTED', :git => 'http://redacted.url/'
```

This works on developer machines since the git credentials are stored in the Keychain

However, when running on a Jenkins server, I get the following error when running "pod install --verbose":

```
Fetching external sources
-> Pre-downloading: `REDACTED` from `http://redacted.url`, commit `f68b8d72e102b09e4e14c35f86554de3e7dca69d`
 > Git download
 > Git download
     $ /usr/local/bin/git clone http://redacted.url /var/folders/_1/glwc5_xs2g14lrh3xr28z5z000008b/T/d20190205-78943-lhtlg2 --template=
     Cloning into '/var/folders/_1/glwc5_xs2g14lrh3xr28z5z000008b/T/d20190205-78943-lhtlg2'...
     fatal: could not read Username for 'http://redacted.url': Device not configured

[!] Error installing REDACTED
[!] Failed to download 'REDACTED'.
```

This says to me that it couldn't clone the repository due to credentials.
Ideally, I'd like to continue using HTTPS rather than SSL so all developers don't need to set up SSH keys although if need be, it would be possible to use SSH on the Jenkins server.

Is there a way to specify the credentials as part of the build script? Such as arguments in "pod install".

Thanks,
James